# Convert string into an array of arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string as follows:

```
my_string = "['page1',5],['page2',3],['page3',8]";
```

I want to convert this into the following:

```
my_array = [['page1',5],['page2',3],['page3',8]];
```

I know that there is a split function in which i have to specify delimiter.When i did this:-

```
my_string.split(',');
```

I got the following result:

```
 ["['page1'", "5]", "['page2'", "3]", "['page3'", "8]"]
```

Comment: Show us what you already have tried.

Comment: Have you tried JSON.parse(my_string) ? this will convert into array

Comment: That's an invalid JSON string. You're better off fixing where and how that string gets created than play around with `split`, `replace` or some regex

Comment: @TheParam It's not a valid JSON string.

Comment: @TheParam the input string is not JSON. [JSON](http://json.org) uses double quotes (`"`) to enclose the strings and it encodes a single object. The string posted in the question contains multiple objects separated by comma.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a string with arrays to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397094/how-to-convert-a-string-with-arrays-to-an-array)

Comment: Why don't you use the JSON syntax? That's exactly what it's made for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you should try and do is to make `my_string` a valid JSON string. That means that instead of single quotes (`'`) you have double quotes (`"`) around your strings. To create a JSON string like this, you can use `JSON.stringify()` on the data you want to be converted into a string. Below is a valid JSON string of your array which you can use `JSON.parse(my_string)` on:

```js
const my_string = '[["page1",5],["page2",3],["page3",8]]';
const res = JSON.parse(my_string);
console.log(res);
```

If you can't do this for whatever reason, then you can try one of the below options.

You can use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to make your string a valid JSON string that is parseable like so:

```js
const my_string = "['page1',5],['page2',3],['page3',8]",
stringified = '['+my_string.replace(/'/g, '"')+']';

console.log(JSON.parse(stringified));
```

Or you can use a [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor to "loosly" parse your JSON. Note that you should only use this if `my_string` is coming from a trusted source (ie: not user input):

```js
const  my_string  = "['page1',5],['page2',3],['page3',8]";
arr = Function('return [' +  my_string + ']')(); 

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eval()` function to convert your string to an array. See the code below.

```js
my_string = "['page1',5],['page2',3],['page3',8]";

my_array = eval(`[${my_string}]`);

console.log(my_array);
```

However, using the `eval()` function comes with a set of drawbacks if not used properly. Please read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) before using `eval` in any of your serious code.

Comment: I would never recommend someone to use `evil`

Comment: @Maurice I would rather recommend taming the evil.

Comment: Though i cannot upvote because my reputation is less than 15 but your solution did exactly the same what i wanted. So thanks bhai. @Vivek

Answer (score -1):

first split the string with "],[" and you got an array like bellow

```
splitted_string = ["[page1,5", "[page2,3" , "[page3,8"];
```

then loop this array and get rid of "[" character and you got an array like bellow

```
splitted_string = ["page1,5", "page2,3" , "page3,8"];
```

finally loop this array and split the each element with ",". viola! you got what you want like bellow

```
splitted_string =  [['page1',5],['page2',3],['page3',8]];
```