# Execute Javascript code using the textarea

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea and it contains the javascript code. I want to execute this code using API and want to send the response after executing.

Like

```
var a = 'some text'
var b = 'ather text'
var c = 123;
var d = a + ' ' +b + ' ' + c;
d + '';
```

In this case I should get the response

```
'some text ather text 123'
```

It is the same as podio calculation field works.
I can execute this code using the *eval* function but due to some security concern I do not want to use eval.

Thank you :)

Comment: So you want to send the code to a server, let it execute there, and receive the response? That can bring way more security issues than using eval

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058482/javascript-eval-and-security

Comment: Yes I want to do that for now.

Comment: If you insist on doing that, I suggest using something like puppeteer (headless chrome web browser automation) to inject your js on a, online js interpreter and manage to send back the response

Comment: Puppeteer is a novel idea but seems like it'd be super slow. Surely there's an eval API somewhere--vaguely recall TIO (try it online) offers one? Either way, this question has been asked before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run user-submitted scripts securely in a node.js sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446729/how-to-run-user-submitted-scripts-securely-in-a-node-js-sandbox)