# How to turn Javascript object value into array when the value is wrapped in quotes?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

How can this javascript object value that is a string be converted into an array, removing the outer quotes, leaving just the brackets? The attempt of using `obj["text-font"] = obj["text-font"].split('"').join("");` was not successful.

Current

```
text-font: "['Open Sans Regular', 'Arial Unicode MS Regular']"
```

Intended

```
text-font: ['Open Sans Regular', 'Arial Unicode MS Regular']
```

Comment: It would be easier if your string was valid JSON (with double quotes, not single ones). Then you could just do: `JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: Why are you using `split('"')`? There are no `"` characters in the string.

Comment: Where is this coming from? Maybe you can fix the source to generate a normal array or valid JSON, instead of this nonstandard format.

Comment: @Barmar went back and fixed the source, sending over a string with items separated by commas then used obj["text-font"].split(", "); thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know there are no other quotes in the strings other than the ones that delimit the font names, you can convert them to double quotes and then use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an array.

```
obj['text-font'] = JSON.parse(obj['text-font'].replace(/'/g, '"'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the single quotes with double ones and then use JSON.parse() to convert it into an actual Array of Strings.

```js
obj["text-font"] = JSON.parse(obj["text-font"].replaceAll("'",'"'))
```

Have a look here for more information:
[MDN Web Docs: JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: The problem is that the array elements are between single brackets **'** instead of double **"**, which is why the JSON.parse won't work. It's good measure to test your solution before replying so you can give better answers in the future!

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the comments. I've now corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) ** though be aware of the security concerns, see below

```js
let obj = {
  "text-font": "['Open Sans Regular', 'Arial Unicode MS Regular']"
}

console.log(eval(obj['text-font']))

// to fix the object

obj['text-font'] = eval(obj['text-font']);
console.log(obj)
```

[eval() has security risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39058482/javascript-eval-and-security#:%7E:text=eval()%20is%20a%20dangerous,the%20privileges%20of%20the%20caller.&text=Any%20malicious%20user%20can%20turn,functions%20to%20be%20executed%20etc.) and malicious users can use the in-browser debugger to execute their own javascript through [XSS attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) - the general advice is not to use it recklessly.

Comment: ***At least*** include a banner with the drawbacks and security vulnerabilites of `eval` before mentioning it in an answer!

Comment: @FZs - good point, done. Feel free to elaborate more on it if desired.